# Remove repeated letters from the string

Tags: python

Would appreciate if anyone could provide a short method to remove the repeated letters.

Let's say I have a list of strings `['APPLE', 'BANANA']`.  I want to remove the repeated letters in the list items and the output maintain original order as `['APLE', 'BAN']`. These are for n items in the list.

Comment: Please show us what you have already tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I have tried using iterators but two levels of for loops are taking time. Was looking for some shortcuts which I dont know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary / array to store encountered letters in the word and for each such word, prepare a temporary string accordingly and in the end, push it in your result array.
Something like this :

```
final = []
for word in words:
    s = ''
    seen = {}
    for letter in word:
        if letter in seen:
            pass
        else:
            s += letter
            seen[letter] = True
    final.append(s)
```

Comment: I want to avoid this iterator

Answer (score 0):

This works, a simple oneliner that preserves the order:

```
>>> a = [ 'APPLE', 'GOOGLE', 'BANANA' ]
>>> [''.join( dict.fromkeys(i).keys() ) for i in a]
['APLE', 'GOLE', 'BAN']
```

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. Have you used the property of unique keys in a dictionary? Please explain for my understanding. Thank you

Comment: @SumitSharma dicts are guaranteed to be ordered since python 3.something

Comment: Won't work for older versions of Python, to ensure code portability it's wiser to use an OrderedDict

Comment: @ÓscarLópez python 2 is dead already: "Python 2 End of Life Announced as January 1st 2020"

Comment: @SumitSharma and yes, keys are unique in `dict`

Comment: @lenik you'd be surprised to see how many projects still use old software versions. Better play it safe, just my two cents.

Answer (score 0):

```
words = ['APPLE', 'BANANA']
output = []

for word in words:
    seen = ''
    for char in word:
        if char not in seen:
            seen += char
    output.append(seen)
print(output)
```